# Warning with automatic return type deduction: why do we need decltype when return defines the type anyway?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

This is a question of what do do for the elementsSize() member function, regarding the automatic return type deduction:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename Element>
class ElementVector
{
    std::vector<Element> elementVec_;  

    // Other attributes.

    public: 

        ElementVector() = default; 

        ElementVector(const std::initializer_list<Element>& list)
            :
                elementVec_(list)
        {}

        auto elementsSize() // -> decltype(elementVec_size()) 
        {
            return elementVec_.size(); 
        }
};

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    ElementVector<double> e = {1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5};  

    cout << e.elementsSize() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The code above results in a compiler warning (gcc 4.8.2):

```
main.cpp:20:27: warning: ‘elementsSize’ function uses ‘auto’ type specifier without trailing return type [enabled by default]
         auto elementsSize() // -> decltype(elementVec_size())
```

I have read about the option of automatic return type deduction being made possible for [C++14](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++14) without the use of decltype.

Writing the commented out `decltype` seems weird to me somehow. What am I doing wrong?

*Note*: I know that I could inherit from *std::vector* if there is no vector among "Other attributes", which is precisely the case in my actual problem.

Comment: "I know that I could inherit from `std::vector`" -- That's probably a very bad idea.

Comment: You answered your own question, it was weird to have to write decltype, so C++14 is changing it.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking - you seem to answer your own question. For now, the language requires a return type, since return type deduction didn't make it into C++11 for normal functions (only for lambdas); so you need to give one (using `decltype` or otherwise). If and when you have a compiler that supports deduction (which, as you say, should become standard later this year), you can omit it.

Comment: @Jefffrey: actually that option I "borrowed" from boost.geometry. Check out boost/geometry/multi/geometries/multi_polygon.hpp

Comment: @MikeSeymour: ok, so I should just code with decltype and clean that up as soon as gcc gets up to date with C++14?

Comment: @tomislav-maric: Yes. Or maybe just use `size_t`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: one more question - what is the advantage right now of auto+decltype v.s. typedef size_type and and a corresponding return?

Comment: @Jefffrey template
<
    typename Polygon,
    template<typename, typename> class Container = std::vector,
    template<typename> class Allocator = std::allocator
>
class multi_polygon : public Container<Polygon, Allocator<Polygon> >
{
    BOOST_CONCEPT_ASSERT( (concept::Polygon<Polygon>) );
};

Comment: @tomislav-maric: Trailing return types can be based on function parameter types, e.g. `auto add(T1 a, T2 b) -> decltype(a+b)`. Leading return types can't.

Comment: @tomislav-maric well, that doesn't change the fact that it's a bad idea. The destructor of `std::vector` is not declared `virtual`. Do you know what does it mean?

Comment: @Jefffrey: undefined behavior when an object of the class derived from std::vector is destroyed when allocated on a heap using a pointer to base (std::vector), right? what if I just want to adapt the vector interface to my needs without composition forcing me into re-writing the entire public interface for std::vector? If I have no additional attributes in the adapter, this should be fine, right?

Comment: @SplinterOfChaos: You should not answer questions by writing comments. You should answer questions by writing answers.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

Nothing. GCC 4.8 implements auto-deduced return types, but as an enabled-by-default C++1y feature. Compiling with `-std=c++1y` will remove that warning.

<sub>[Answer converted from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21258062/warning-with-automatic-return-type-deduction-why-do-we-need-decltype-when-retur#comment32638473_21258062).]</sub>